# Which is the right way to know which button rised the callback in kivy?

Tags: kivy

I'm learning kivy..
I want to draw an array of buttons, which rise the same callback, so I want to know which button was pressed. I've seen a lot of similar questions, but without a functional answer.

What I did is:

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from functools import partial

class TestKivyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        main_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        btn = []
        for i in range(10):
            btn.append(Button(text="Btn %s" % i))
            btn[i].bind(on_press=partial(self.on_anything, btn=i))
            main_layout.add_widget(btn[i])

        return main_layout

    def on_anything(self, *args, **kwargs):
        but_pressed = kwargs.get("btn")
        print("Pressed button n.", but_pressed)


root = TestKivyApp()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root.run()
```

This does what I need, but I don't like it..
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You receive the button that was pressed as the first argument to the callback.

Comment: yes, i've seen that, but how can it be of use? it returns the object number, but that is unrelated to the array position, for example.

Comment: If the button object doesn't contain enough information to do whatever it is you're after, create a button subclass and add more state to store what you want. Or, instead of binding `partial(self.on_anything, btn=i)` do `partial(self.on_anything, btn=i, some_other_argument=whatever_you_like)`.

Comment: but partial(self.on_anything, btn=i) already does what I want, letting me know which button in the array was hit. But i find it strange to add a variable (btn) to pass an argument I should already know. I'm sorry if it is a silly question, but i come from java and not everything is trivial to understand.

Comment: Like I said, the button that was pressed is passed as the first argument to the callback. That's true regardless of whether you also pass it yourself as a named argument, like you've done here. I'm not clear if you've understood this, since you use `*args` to catch and ignore that automatically-passed argument.